# full screen background image while using uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I have an UINavigationController with UINavigationBar hidden = YES.

I want full screen bg for view that embedded in UINavigationController.

But I get only that:
http://cs616618.vk.me/v616618797/1bf0d/FEdIn0Nn4x8.jpg

Is it possible to make it full screen under status bar?
I achieved that with standalone view controller, but while using it in UINavigationController it becomes like on image.

Comment: Do you want the status bar to be hidden?

Comment: No, I just want the image to be under status bar
like this:
http://cs616618.vk.me/v616618797/1bf14/OyI0vvOv3-Y.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that all your view controllers are correctly configured:

The `UINavigationController`:

[image: <code>UINavigationController</code> configuration]

The `rootViewController` (inside the `UINavigationController`):

[image: <code>UIViewController</code> configuration]

Here's the result I get using the above configuration and an "Aspect fill" setting on the `UIImageView`:

[image: Full screen image behind status bar]

If you want to do this programmatically, try this:

In your view controller's code:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

And where you're initializing your `UINavigationController` (AppDelegate, etc.):

```
navController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
```

Of course, do not forget to comment or remove all lines of code that could interfere with these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did which worked for me using **Swift 5, XCode 12.**

**Step 1 (Optional) - Create a custom UINavigationController class**

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

Replace your UINavigationController with this UINavigationController subclass. I mark this as optional as this is based on preference, if you do not set this, your navigation bar will be opaque and you cannot see what's beneath it.

Setting the `navigationBar.isTranslucent = true` allows you to see the background beneath it which is what I like. A subclass is also optional but you might need to make other updates to your nav bar so I always like to make this a subclass.

**Step 2 - Set up your background view constraints**

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
  // your background view
  let bgImageView: UIImageView = {
    let bgImageView = UIImageView()
    bgImageView.image = UIImage(named: "gradient_background")
    bgImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return bgImageView
}()

  // Get the height of the nav bar and the status bar so you
  // know how far up your background needs to go
  var topBarHeight: CGFloat {
    var top = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      top += UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
    } else {
      top += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    }
    return top
  }

  var isLayoutConfigured = false

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    title = "Site Visit"

    // you only want to do this once
    if !isLayoutConfigured() {
      isLayoutConfigured = true
      configBackground()
    }
  }

  private func configBackground() {
    view.addSubview(bgImageView)
    configureBackgroundConstraints()
  }
  
  // Set up your constraints, main one here is the top constraint
  private func configureBackgroundConstraints() {
    bgImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bgImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                                     constant: -topBarHeight).isActive = true
    bgImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                         constant: 0).isActive = true
    bgImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                        constant: 0).isActive = true
    bgImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                          constant: 0).isActive = true
    
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Before setting constraints:
[image: UIViewController without NavBar top constraints]

After setting above constraints:
[image: UIViewController with NavBar top constraints]